# Python instance of class defined inside a method is still able to use local variables inside the method when called outside the method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class defined inside a python method as follows

```
c = None
def foo():
   i = 1
   class bar( object ):
      def show( self ):
         print i
   global c
   c = bar()
foo()
print c.show() #prints 1
```

The above code prints 1 which is thee value of `i` .

Where is the 'i' stored for the instance of bar to access ? Instances created outside the class using `c.__class__()` can also access `i`

Comment: Every time the function `foo` gets called, the name `i` is created in its local scope and everything inside `foo`'s function frame gets access to it.  Why is it so strange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing a *closure*; `i` is closed over by the nested scope of `bar.show()`. The same would happen to variables used by nested functions without a class.

You can see the closure by introspecting the method; I've altered your code a little to just return the class as it simplifies things:

```
>>> def foo():
...    i = 1
...    class bar( object ):
...       def show( self ):
...          print i
...    return bar
... 
>>> c = foo()()
>>> c
<__main__.bar object at 0x104c7ac90>
>>> c.show
<bound method bar.show of <__main__.bar object at 0x104c7ac90>>
>>> c.show.__func__
<function show at 0x10535c758>
>>> c.show.__func__.__closure__
(<cell at 0x1132a0440: int object at 0x100502818>,)
>>> c.show.__func__.__closure__[0].cell_contents
1
```

So `c.show` is a bound method, `c.show.__func__` the original `show` function, and `c.show.__func__.__closure__` is the tuple of closure cells. I've accessed the current value of the cell with the `closure.cell_contents` attribute.

The parent function `foo`, is also aware that the variable `i` must be kept around, Python recorded that information in the code object for the function:

```
>>> foo.__code__.co_cellvars
('i',)
```

and the bytecode for the function creates a closure cell as part of the code:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_DEREF              0 (i)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('bar')
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (object)
             12 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             15 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (i)
             18 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             21 LOAD_CONST               3 (<code object bar at 0x1132a4bb0, file "<stdin>", line 3>)
             24 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             27 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             30 BUILD_CLASS         
             31 STORE_FAST               0 (bar)

  6          34 LOAD_FAST                0 (bar)
             37 RETURN_VALUE
```

The [`LOAD_CLOSURE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_CLOSURE) and [`MAKE_CLOSURE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-MAKE_CLOSURE) byte codes work together to produce closure cells and passing it on to the code object that will produce the class (handled by the `LOAD_CONST` bytecode at index 21); the class bytecode passes that closure on again to the `show` function:

```
>>> dis.dis(foo.__code__.co_consts[3])
  3           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (__name__)
              3 STORE_NAME               1 (__module__)

  4           6 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (i)
              9 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object show at 0x1132a4330, file "<stdin>", line 4>)
             15 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             18 STORE_NAME               2 (show)
             21 LOAD_LOCALS         
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

Inside `bar.show()`, the closure is also handled with a special bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis(c.show)
  5           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (i)
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

The [`LOAD_DEREF` opcode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_DEREF) loads the cell at index `0` just as I did above.

Answer (score 3):

You're accessing the variable via a [closure](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)).  In python2.x, `i`'s value is actually stored on the `show` function object in the `func_closure`<sup>1</sup> attribute:

```
>>> c = None
>>> def foo():
...    i = 1
...    class bar( object ):
...       def show( self ):
...          print i
...    global c
...    c = bar()
... 
>>> foo()
>>> c.show.im_func.func_closure[0].cell_contents
1
```

We can gain a little more insight by looking at the disassembed bytecode:

```
>>> dis.dis(c.show.im_func)
  5           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (i)
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Ahh, so it looks like objects that are accessed via closures are loaded by the `LOAD_DEREF` OP code which also tells python which cell to look in (in this case the 0th).

<sup><sup>1</sup>`__closure__` and `__func__` are the python3.x names for `func_closure` and `im_func`, respectively.  They're aliased in python2.6 to aid with writing forward compatible code.</sup>

Comment: [Python 2.6](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.6.html#other-language-changes) introduced the forward compatibility aliases, actually. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I should have guessed that (seeing that's when they started to introduce most of the forward compatibility features).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior. The class that you defined will work like a closure function: it will have access to its enclosing scope -- in your case the `foo` function.

You can refer to the [official documentation on scopes and namespaces](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).